# Create combinations of strings and according to combination calculate something (Python)

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Let's say I have the following items:

```
items = [["1", 2, 10], ["2", 2, 6], ["3", 4, 11], ["4", 2, 4], ["5", 3, 5]]
```

where the string is just a continuous number. The second value in the lists describes the weight of the item, the third value describes the value of the particular item.

I want to create all possible combinations of these items (from just 1 to 1+2+5 or 4+2+3+5+1) and then, for every combination, calculate the weight of the combination. Such as, that, e.g. in the case for the "item 1+2+5" example the total weight would be 2+2+3 = 7. This should be done for every combination. In addition, I need to calculate the value of these 3 items. However, the restriction is a maximum weight of, let's say x!

I have the following so far:

```
from itertools import *

x5 = permutations("12345", 5)
x4 = permutations("12345", 4)
x3 = permutations("12345", 3)
x2 = permutations("12345", 2)
x1 = permutations("12345", 1)

x5 = list(x5)
x4 = list(x4)
x3 = list(x3)
x2 = list(x2)
x1 = list(x1)

x5.append(x4)
x5.append(x3)
x5.append(x2)
x5.append(x1)

combs = x5.
```

This gives me all the combinations.. but from there on I am absolutely clueless.

Comment: How weights are computed?How is weight of `1+2+5` =>`2+2+3 = 7`

Comment: 1+2+5 refer to the items 1, 2, 5. item 1 has a weight of 2 (2nd item in the lists). Item 2 has a weight of 2.

Comment: What's the expected output? You don't have to list the whole thing, but you should at least show us a fragment of it.

Comment: The expected output is that for every combination of items, the corresponding weight is given.

Answer (score 0):

There are `2 ** (len(items)) - 1` combinations to explore. You can treat this as a bit-vector and easily iterate over it:

```
items = [["1", 2, 10], ["2", 2, 6], ["3", 4, 11], ["4", 2, 4], ["5", 3, 5]]

for i in range(2**len(items) - 1):
    bitvec = bin(i)[2:]   # convert to string containing 0 and 1
    selected = [items[k] for k, b in enumerate(bitvec) if b=='1']
    # selected now contains a unique combination from items
```

Comment: It tells me TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all of the combinations, their weights, and their values, and lets you filter by max weight.

```
items = [["1", 2, 10], ["2", 2, 6], ["3", 4, 11], ["4", 2, 4], ["5", 3, 5]]

res = []
max_wt = 100
for i in range(len(items)):
    combo = []
    combo_wt = 0
    combo_val = 0
    for j in range(len(items)-i):
        combo+=items[i+j][0]
        combo_wt+=items[i+j][1]
        combo_val+=items[i+j][2]
        print(combo, combo_wt, combo_val)
        if (combo_wt < max_wt):
            arr=[]
            arr+=(combo, combo_wt, combo_val)
            res.append(arr)
print(res)
```

Note that you have permutations, and not combinations, in your code, though you ask for combinations (which makes the most sense in this sort of problem; I'm thinking of the 'I'm a treasure hunter and can only carry so much weight. Which items should I take to maximize my profit?' kind of problem)

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to need are combinations, not permutations (permutations of a given combination will give the same total weight)

In order to compute the weight totals, it will be easier to create a dictionary with your strings as key and the corresponding weights as value.

Then the combination to total weight structure can easily be built using a dictionary comprehension.

Here's how you could do it:

```
from itertools import *

items = [["1", 2, 10], ["2", 2, 6], ["3", 4, 11], ["4", 2, 4], ["5", 3, 5]]

values  = [item[0] for item in items]
weights = {item[0]:item[1] for item in items}
combos  = []
for size in range(len(values)): combos += combinations(values,size+1)
comboWeights = { combo:sum([weights[value] for value in combo]) for combo in combos }
```

The resulting comboWeights dictionary has combination tuples as keys and total weights as values:

```
for combo,weight in comboWeights.items(): print(combo,weight)

('1',) 2
('2',) 2
('3',) 4
('4',) 2
('5',) 3
('1', '2') 4
('1', '3') 6
('1', '4') 4
('1', '5') 5
('2', '3') 6
('2', '4') 4
('2', '5') 5
('3', '4') 6
('3', '5') 7
('4', '5') 5
('1', '2', '3') 8
('1', '2', '4') 6
('1', '2', '5') 7
('1', '3', '4') 8
('1', '3', '5') 9
('1', '4', '5') 7
('2', '3', '4') 8
('2', '3', '5') 9
('2', '4', '5') 7
('3', '4', '5') 9
('1', '2', '3', '4') 10
('1', '2', '3', '5') 11
('1', '2', '4', '5') 9
('1', '3', '4', '5') 11
('2', '3', '4', '5') 11
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') 13
```